# What is a multicast graph?

Tags: graph-theory, queueing-theory

Martin Fowler in his blog post on "[The LMAX Architecture](http://martinfowler.com/articles/lmax.html)" tried to describe the component called Disruptor as a multicast graph of queues

> At a crude level you can think of a Disruptor as a multicast graph of
>   queues where producers put objects on it that are sent all the
>   consumers for parallel consumption through separate downstream
>   queues...

I'm having difficulties understanding the nature of a multicast graph

Comment: This question currently doesn't have enough information to get a good answer (which is why it seems to have been downvoted by one person, though downvoting without leaving a comment is discouraged here). Can you link to the blog post you're referring to, at a minimum? Also, "I'm having difficulties understanding the nature" is a bit too vague - it's necessary to ask at least a somewhat more specific question, or else this might be better as a comment to the blog post than a post on CSTheory :-).

Comment: Thanks for adding the link. "Multicast graph" isn't anything I know about personally, but the authors do indeed talk about it like it's some standard data structure/networking thingamagig. Hopefully someone else here can help you!

Comment: @Rob Simmons I downvote without comment with using my smart phone since it would take too long to enter the comment. I downvoted because I don't think this is research level.

Comment: @Tyson I'm not sure the (edited) question is not-research-level, though it's probably borderline. The blog post uses the term "multicast graph" as if it's a generalization of the specific thing being considered, the term is not easily Wikipedia-able, and the first matches on Google aren't helpful. (We're allowed to disagree, of course :-).)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a technical paper on the LMAX Architecture (I just followed a link found on the blog you linked here): http://disruptor.googlecode.com/files/Disruptor-1.0.pdf

An example of a multicast graph is on page 9 of the PDF. There are also examples of multicast graphs (compared to various other options) here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast

Comment: The link does not work.